# Is it possible to log into a website using OpenID that doesn't provide a ClientID and a Client Secret with requests in Python?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, openid-connect

I'm trying to do some web scraping using Python with requests and bs4.
I want to access data that is behind a log in. The website uses OpenID Connect.

I understood that I have to use OAuth2 (as in this url : https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#web-application-flow) to succeed my log in.
The problem is : this method requires a Client ID and a Client Secret, but the website doesn't provide these two. There is no way to create a developper account like in Google or Twitter to get these two.

Is there another way to succeed an authentification through an OpenID Connect form ?
Even if we have to manually log in with a web browser and then get the data with Python it would be okay too.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this without any interaction with the main API. I think you can somehow get the Authorization URL from the first domain, but if they added an security layer (redirect_url, only allow redirects to whitelisted domains), this wouldn't be helpful. Maybe you can try something with selenium or some engines like this

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was indeed very easy with selenium to log into the website. Then I get the cookies from the selenium connection and I enter the cookies in a session of the library requests and voilà !